# Firebase performance, which approach is better?

Tags: performance, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Imagine a database structured this way:

[image]

If I need to display only a few of this info, not all of them, which approach is better?

**Approach 1**

download the whole node with:

```
getInfo(userId){
  firebase.database().ref("userinfo/" + userId)
    .on("value", (info => {
      //code here
    }))
}
```

and, once I have the whole info, show only what I need

or

**Approach 2**

download only the nodes that I need, this would imply a few calls running at the same time, example:

```
getInfoByNode(userId){
  firebase.database().ref("userinfo/" + userId + "/name")
    .on("value", (name => {
      //code here
    }))
  firebase.database().ref("userinfo/" + userId + "/email")
    .on("value", (email=> {
      //code here
    }))
  firebase.database().ref("userinfo/" + userId + "/phone")
    .on("value", (phone=> {
      //code here
    }))
}
```

Comment: Be careful when storing BSB/Account Number information, ensure that your business is PCI DDS compliant as required. Also if you know you're always fetching those details you could break the data into another sub object like `/userinfo/${userId}/details` and `details` could be an object `{ name, email, phone }`. Meaning you can access their details with one request instead of three and without the bloat.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We are storing that info in order to pay users. We are using Stripe for payments from users to us. Do we still need to be PCI DDS compliant?
Also, your idea is a very good one. If you had to choose between the two approaches above, which one would you choose?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to optimize something that doesn't need any optimization.  You're not dealing with very much data here.  The difference between the two methods is not significant for the size of data here.  If you really need to optimize this, you should perform your own benchmarks and compare the results.

Comment: Offtopic: Yes, you still need compliance to store the information regardless of it being for credits or debits. I believe Stripe can tokenlize this data for you - and they are compliant. So you can look into hosting the BSB/Account with them and get back a token which can be used to credit customers accounts.